# Group list of dictionary based on particular key and add another value to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries like these

```
l = [
     {'vehicle': 708.75, 'general': None, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH'},
     {'vehicle': None, 'general': 1044.48, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH'},
     {'vehicle': None, 'general': 7035.0, 'salesperson': 'MATHEW'},
    ]
```

I am trying to change the form new list of dictionary like this .

expected output

```
l = [
     {'vehicle': 708.75, 'general': 1044.48, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH'},
     {'vehicle': None, 'general': 7035.0, 'salesperson': 'MATHEW'},
    ]
```

I am trying to group the salesperson and add general or vehicle value to it.
I try like this

```
import collections
res = collections.defaultdict(list) 
for i in l:
    for key, val in i.items(): 
        res[val].append(key) 
print(res)
```

but it shows wrong result.any suggestions to get this??

Comment: What do you mean *"wrong result"*? Given that you want a list of dictionaries with string values, why start with `defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: I tried to group and append value to it.Finally add list to it .that not done in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simply iterating through the datastructure

```
[root@cscale-82-69 python]# cat stck.py
l = [
     {'vehicle': 708.75, 'general': None, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH'},
     {'vehicle': None, 'general': 1044.48, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH'},
     {'vehicle': None, 'general': 7035.0, 'salesperson': 'MATHEW'},
    ]


y = []
for each in l:
 name = each['salesperson']
 count = 0
 for _ in y:
  if _['salesperson'] == name:
   count += 1
   for key, val in _.items():
    if _[key] == None:
     _[key] = each[key]
 if count == 0:
  y.append(each)

print (l)
print (y)
[root@cscale-82-69 python]# python stck.py
[{'general': 1044.48, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH', 'vehicle': 708.75}, {'general': 1044.48, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH', 'vehicle': None}, {'general': 7035.0, 'salesperson': 'MATHEW', 'vehicle': None}]
[{'general': 1044.48, 'salesperson': 'SAJANEESH', 'vehicle': 708.75}, {'general': 7035.0, 'salesperson': 'MATHEW', 'vehicle': None}]
[root@cscale-82-69 python]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for unique lists:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

key = itemgetter('vehicle')
print([next(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(l, key=key), key=key)])
```